# Breakpoints not being hit in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I've the following main code located in `MyCityApp.kt` which calls Screen composables if the app is opened in **Compact** mode (i.e. a phone or foldable) or calls `MyCityHomeScreen` in case the app is opened in **Expanded** mode (i.e. a tablet):

```kotlin
sealed class MyCityScreen(val route: String) {
    object Categories: MyCityScreen("Categories")
    object Recommendations: MyCityScreen("Recommendations")
    object Recommendation: MyCityScreen("Recommendation/{recommendationId}") {
        fun createRoute(recommendationId: Long) = "Recommendation/$recommendationId"
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyCityApp(
    windowSize: WindowWidthSizeClass,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val viewModel: MyCityViewModel = viewModel()
    val myCityUiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value

    val contentType: MyCityContentType = when (windowSize) {
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> {
            MyCityContentType.LIST_ONLY
        }
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium -> {
            MyCityContentType.LIST_ONLY
        }
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> {
            MyCityContentType.LIST_AND_DETAIL
        }
        else -> {
            MyCityContentType.LIST_ONLY
        }
    }

    if (contentType != MyCityContentType.LIST_AND_DETAIL) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = MyCityScreen.Categories.route
        ) {
            composable(route = MyCityScreen.Categories.route) {
                val categories = myCityUiState.categories

                MyCityCategoriesScreen(
                    categories = categories,
                    myCityUiState = myCityUiState,
                    navController = navController,
                    viewModel = viewModel
                )
            }

            composable(route = MyCityScreen.Recommendations.route) {
                val recommendations = myCityUiState.currentRecommendations

                MyCityRecommendationsScreen(
                    recommendations = recommendations,
                    myCityUiState = myCityUiState,
                    navController = navController
                )
            }

            composable(
                route = MyCityScreen.Recommendation.route,
                arguments = listOf(navArgument("recommendationId") {
                    type = NavType.IntType
                })
            ) { backStackEntry ->
                val recommendationId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("recommendationId")
                val recommendation =
                    myCityUiState.allRecommendations[recommendationId!!]

                MyCityRecommendationDetailScreen(
                    recommendation = recommendation,
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
        }
    } else {
        MyCityHomeScreen(
            contentType = contentType,
            myCityUiState = myCityUiState,
            onCategoryCardPressed = {
                viewModel.updateRecommendations(category = it)
            },
            onDetailScreenBackPressed = {
                viewModel.resetHomeScreenStates()
            },
            onRecommendationCardPressed = {
                viewModel.updateDetailsScreenStates(
                    category = myCityUiState.currentSelectedCategory,
                    recommendation = it
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Code of `MyCityHomeScreen` is:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyCityHomeScreen(
    contentType: MyCityContentType,
    myCityUiState: MyCityUiState,
    onCategoryCardPressed: (Category) -> Unit,
    onRecommendationCardPressed: (Recommendation) -> Unit,
    onDetailScreenBackPressed: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    if (myCityUiState.isShowingHomepage) {
        MyCityAppContent(
            contentType = contentType,
            myCityUiState = myCityUiState,
            onCategoryCardPressed = onCategoryCardPressed,
            onRecommendationCardPressed = onRecommendationCardPressed,
            modifier = modifier
        )
    } else {
        MyCityDetailsScreen(
            myCityUiState = myCityUiState,
            isFullScreen = true,
            onBackPressed = onDetailScreenBackPressed,
            modifier = Modifier
        )
    }
}
```

I've placed two breakpoints: one on `MyCityAppContent` and one on `MyCityDetailsScreen`, respectively.

Running the app in tablet mode however doesn't trigger any of them. Placing `Log.d(...)` call to log it has entered the `if` statement before calling `MyCityAppContent` results in the log being triggered.

Why is it then that the breakpoints on the composables are not triggered? One of them must be triggered (`MyCityAppContent`), however this doesn't happen.

Android Studio I'm running is latest:

```
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709, built on January 18, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true


Current Desktop: i3
```

Tried running with both Resizable AVD (tablet mode) and Pixel Tablet API 34.

Comment: i'm assuming you've actually attached the debugger, right ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I simply used `Log.d(...)` to see what paths the code took when I clicked on different composables in the AVD.

Still unclear why the breakpoints are not triggered.